# Regex - converting to CamelCase and cutting founded word

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3, boost-regex

### Problem 1

Lets say I have this word `realPersonId` and want to find in text and replace it with word without `Id` suffix. First letter needs to be capital. I can't get that capital.

Sample text: `realPersonId`
Find expression: `(\s+)(.*)Id`
Replace expression: `\1\2`
Result: `realPerson`
Wanted result: `RealPerson`

### Problem 2

In this problem I don't have any solution, all I want with sample text is to replace it with concatenated text, size of maximum 26 letters.

Sample text: `table="EXAMPLE_INFORMATION_123456789"`
Find expression: `table="(.*)"`
Replace expression: `\1`
Result: `EXAMPLE_INFORMATION_123456789`
Wanted result: `EXAMPLE_INFORMATION_123456`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem `1` solution:

```
Find What: (\w+)Id
Replace With: \u\1
```

**Note**: The following modifiers may be used to change the case of the backreference during the replacement:

```
\l     # first character to lower case
\u     # first character to upper case
\L     # start of lower case conversion
\U     # start of upper case conversion
\E     # end lower/upper case conversion
```

Problem `2` solution:

```
Find What: table="(.{26})[^"]+"
Replace With: \1
```

This captures exactly 26 characters and discards the rest using a negated class outside the capturing group, if you want a minimum you could use `.{min,26}`, the dot `.` will match any character except newline.

Comment: Thanks hwnd. Solution 1 works perfectly, Solution 2 is good but I'm having some problems. It want find me names shorter than 26 characters, like this `table="EXAMPLE_INFORMATION"`. I want to do something like this: if it's shorter than 26 characters live it as is, if longer cut it. I want `"` to be a break.

Comment: Try `table="(.{1,26}).*?"`

Comment: That's it :) Thank you very much. Do you have any books, articles or some tutorial on the web to recommend?